# output is not showing at output screen

Tags: java

```
public class Try1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char ch;
        for(ch='a' ;ch<='z'; ch++);     
        { 
            System.out.println(ch);
        }   
    }
}
```

could not get output

Comment: remove ;  of for loop

Comment: wrong place ";" in for def---  and what is your input?

Comment: You should be getting some output. At least "z" :D. But really, other comments already got it.

Comment: Actually, @m4ktub, not `z` but `{`, because `z` still falls within the loop condition.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right, off course. Thanks. I just wanted to make a joke; that's what I get.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char ch;
    for(ch='a' ;ch<='z'; ch++)
    {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

You've used ; after for loop.

Answer (score 0):

for this "for(ch='a' ;ch<='z'; ch++);" statement, are you sure about last semicolumn, it breaks your for loop right there only.